# Checkbox actions

Tags: php, checkbox, action

I need the checkbox to be checked ONLY if `$c` (POST) is 1 or if `$d['is']` is 1.

Here is my code:

```
if ( ($d['is'] == 1) OR $c == 1)

$data = 'checked="checked"';
```

The problem is, if checkbox is checked, and I uncheck this and hit the submit button it is still checked because `$d['is']` is still 1. So at the end: it should check the box only if `$c` (POST) is 1 or if `$d['is']` is 1 but if `$c == 0` (POST) (unchecked checkbox) checkbox shouldnt be checked.

It's hard to desribe my problem, so if you don't understand anything, please just post a comment.

Comment: Just to be sure, I suggest you to use === instead of == because of the type comparison.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa
What do you mean?

Comment: if you use the == you got TRUE in this case:

if $c's value is 1,  $c == 1   ----> TRUE
if $c's value is TRUE,  $c == 1   ----> TRUE

More details here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

So what you're saying is you want it checked if `$c==1` or `$d['is'] == 1`, but not if `$c==0`? If this is the case, why does `$d['is']` come into it at all? Just have it checked if `$c==1` and you're done...

Comment: Then , checkbox will be unchecked as default :/.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is `$c` by default?

Comment: `$c`, by default is 0 (not set), IF I check the box, `$c` is 1.

Comment: Have you considered `isset($c)`? In that case you could have `if(!isset($c)) $c = 1;` and have it work the way you want.

Comment: Not if `$c=0` to start with, which I believe is what you're after.